# how can I install GraphLab Create ?anaconda envs Py2.7;OS X

Tags: python, anaconda, graphlab

When I install GraphLab Create though GraphLab Create Launcher. I meet these errors:
    There was a problem updating the conda package.  Restart GraphLab Create Launcher.
    Unable to update conda:
    Fetching package metadata .............
    Solving package specifications: .

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda 4.0.8* -> conda-env <2.5 -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

OS X; three python.

```
/usr/bin   # py2
/Users/xxxx/anaconda/ #py3
/Users/xxxx/anaconda/envs/gl-env #py2
```

I also install install GraphLab Create through command line, 
error is this :

```
raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

how can I install  GraphLab Create ?